# How to remove the :id Part when doing a Concern

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications, routes, nested-routes

My routes file contains:

```
  concern :generic_table do
    get 'search_suggestions' => 'search_suggestions'
  end

  get 'human_resources/' => 'human_resources#index'
  namespace :human_resources do
    get 'settings/' => 'settings#index'
    namespace :settings do
      resources :constants do
        concerns :generic_table
      end
    end
  end
```

And it produces:

```
/human_resources/settings/constants/:constant_id/search_suggestions(.:format) 

human_resources/settings/search_suggestions#search_suggestions
```

I am trying to remove the `/:constant_id/` part and it point to the controller action:

```
human_resources/settings/constants/search_suggestions#search_suggestions
```

So in finality it would be

```
/human_resources/settings/constants/search_suggestions(.:format)

human_resources/settings/constants/search_suggestions#search_suggestions
```

How can I remove the `/:constant_id/` part; and point it directly to my controllers action so my search bar my access the search suggestion for AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to replace the `resources` block by a `namespace` one. It is the `resources` block that generates the parameter.

See also the `member` block if you need `id` instead of `constant_id`.

One extra point: This may not generate the route helpers you want. There are extra options to pass to `namespace` and related to tailor the helpers.